# returnの仕方ついて

Tags: javascript

**returnの仕方ついて**

以下の２つのコードの、◆箇所について考えています。

```
【1】
    function rangeOfNumbers (start, end) {      
        if ( start === end) {   
            return [startNum];
        }else{  
            var answer = rangeOfNumbers(start, end - 1);
        　◆answer.push(end);
          ◆return answer;
        }   
    }
    rangeOfNumbers(5,8);        //(4) [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

.

```
【2】
   function rangeOfNumbers (start, end) {       
        if ( start === end) {   
            return [start];
        }else{  
            var answer = rangeOfNumbers(start, end - 1);
        　◆return answer.push(end);
        }   
    }
    rangeOfNumbers(5,8);

    /*Error VM2477:6 Uncaught TypeError: answer.push is not a function
        at rangeOfNumbers (<anonymous>:6:17)
        at rangeOfNumbers (<anonymous>:5:16)
        at <anonymous>:9:1*/
```

**以下、質問です。**

【2】でエラーがでるのは、何故なのでしょうか。

お助けいただければ幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

answer.push は 配列に 項目を追加して その戻り値として 32ビットの整数を返します。
[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
return answer.push(end);
```

は

```
var length = answer.push(end);
return length;
```

と同じで 32ビット整数の値を返します。

そのため その関数の戻り値である 数字を

```
var answer = rangeOfNumbers(start, end - 1);
```

で `answer` に設定し

```
answer.push(end);
```

とすると

数字型には push 関数が存在しないため
`push is not a function` というエラーが表示されています。